# Is there any other literary technique other than metaphor in the following quote?

Tags: homework, literary-techniques

I'm writing an essay required for school, involving the analysis of texts.

> “remove **the shackles of prejudice and intolerance**”

I was wondering if there is any other literary technique in the above quote, other than just a metaphor?

> Context: These, then, are our common hopes that unite us -- that as **the shackles of prejudice and intolerance** fall from our own limbs we can together strive to identify and remove the impediments to human development everywhere. The mechanisms by which this great task is to be achieved provided the proper focus of this great Forum. I feel sure that women throughout the world who, like me, cannot be with you join me now in sending you all our prayers and good wishes for a joyful and productive meeting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's about as straightforward a metaphor as they come. I detect no other figure of speech in that short phrase. Perhaps if you quoted more context something would emerge.

EDIT

Now that I see more context, the phrase taken by itself is still just a metaphor, which is part of a larger *peroration* (summary that concludes a speech). The metaphor may serve as a kind of *metabasis* (a transitional summary) that the speaker is using to persuade the audience that the aspiration that follows ("we can together strive to identify and remove the impediments ...") should be recognized and embraced. Actually, the first part of the sentence ("These, then, are our common hopes that unite us") is the literal metabasis, and the "shackles" metaphor is merely an illuminating restatement of the transitional message.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I have added the context to the question.